# how to edit the date time field only the first time

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a object in a model

`date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)`

Now this saves the current date and time when the entry has been entered into the database, as well as changes the time when the entry has been edited.

Is there any way such that the date and time is changed only when its first entered into the database and not when its edited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) rather than `auto_add`.

`auto_now_add` is used to:

> [automatically] set the field to now **when the object is first created**. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it's not just a default value that you can override.

Whereas `auto_now` is to:

> [automatically] set the field to now **every time the object is saved**. Useful for "last-modified" timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it's not just a default value that you can override.